# How to use below date picker in jsp file?

Tags: datepicker

I m using the date picker in my jsp page but i m getting the error in my browser console such as:
 **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionobsSerach.jsp:14 (anonymous function)jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 e.extend.readyjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 c.addEventListener.B
.**

**Code :**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

please check and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have included different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI .

Kindly change it accordingly.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```